# Passing string and hash ref to subroutines

Tags: perl

I am passing a string and a hash to a subroutine where the hash is accepted as a reference to the subroutine. At the end of the subroutine call, I expect my hash to be filled. Snapshot:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8

sub passHashAndFile {
  my ($file, $hashRef) = @_;
  open(HANDLE, $file) or die("Can not open file $file \n");
    while(<HANDLE>) {
      my @splitted_values = split("--", $_);
      $hashRef->{$spllited_values[0]} = $hashRef->{$spllited_values[1]};
    }
  close(HANDLE);
}

my %hash;
passHashAndFile("test.txt", %hash);
foreach my $elem (keys %hash) {
  print "Key = $elem, Value = $hash{$elem}\n";
}
```

And my test.txt looks like this:

```
1--2
3--4
5--6
7--8
```

I am catching hash as an reference and then dereferencing it to fill the values. What wrong did it do?

Comment: You're not passing a hash ref...

Comment: You also need to assign `$spllited_values[1]` to `$hashRef->{$spllited_values[0]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
passHashAndFile("test.txt", %hash);
```

should be

```
passHashAndFile("test.txt", \%hash);
```

---

Additionally, you have misspelled variable names, you assigning the wrong value, you're using unlocalized global vars, and you're using problematic 2-arg `open`. Also, most people would have the sub return a hash ref instead of taking a ref to an empty hash.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8

use strict;
use warnings;

sub parse_file {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open file \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   my %hash;
   while (my $line = <$fh>) {
      my ($key, $val) = split(/--/, $line);
      $hash{$key} = $val;
   }

   return \%hash;
}

my $hash = parse_file("test.txt");
for my $key (keys %$hash) {
   print "Key = $key, Value = $hash->{$key}\n";
}
```

We usually leave out of our answers, but **always** use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have found at least one of the problems.